# Dragging SVG element over another SVG element

Tags: javascript, svg

Is there any way i can drag an SVG element over another SVG element? I tried but like in [this](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/sites/files/peter/drag_elements.svg) tutorial i can only drag the one i placed the second over the first one. There is no way i can drag first one over the second without problems. 
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Here is the whole tutorial: http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/book/export/html/437

Comment: create both SVG's inside a the same parent Div. Set overflow:visible;

Comment: Just set `pointer-events: none;` to all object except for draggable while dragging?

Comment: You are a genius, Ximik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was writing it before I saw that @Strat-O gave you the same approach.

So here is a commented example of that :

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="400" height="200">
    
    <style>
      .draggable {
        cursor: move;
      }
    </style>
    
    <script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
    var selectedElement = 0;
    var currentX = 0;
    var currentY = 0;
    var currentMatrix = 0;

 function cloneToTop(oldEl){
   // already at top, don't go farther…
   if(oldEl.atTop==true) return oldEl;
   // make a copy of this node
   var el = oldEl.cloneNode(true);
    // select all draggable elements, none of them are at top anymore
   var dragEls= oldEl.ownerDocument.documentElement.querySelectorAll('.draggable');
   for(i=0; i<dragEls.length; i++){
    dragEls[i].atTop=null;
    }
   var parent = oldEl.parentNode;
   // remove the original node
   parent.removeChild(oldEl);
   // insert our new node at top (last element drawn is first visible in svg)
     parent.appendChild(el);
     // Tell the world that our new element is at Top
   el.atTop= true;
   return el;
   }


    function selectElement(evt) {
      selectedElement = cloneToTop(evt.target);
      currentX = evt.clientX;
      currentY = evt.clientY;
      currentMatrix = selectedElement.getAttributeNS(null, "transform").slice(7,-1).split(' ');
    
      for(var i=0; i<currentMatrix.length; i++) {
        currentMatrix[i] = parseFloat(currentMatrix[i]);
      }
      
      selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "onmousemove", "moveElement(evt)");
      selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseout", "deselectElement(evt)");
      selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseup", "deselectElement(evt)");
    }
        
    function moveElement(evt) {
      var dx = evt.clientX - currentX;
      var dy = evt.clientY - currentY;
      currentMatrix[4] += dx;
      currentMatrix[5] += dy;
      
      selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "matrix(" + currentMatrix.join(' ') + ")");
      currentX = evt.clientX;
      currentY = evt.clientY;
    }
        
    function deselectElement(evt) {
      if(selectedElement != 0){
          selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmousemove");
          selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmouseout");
          selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmouseup");
          selectedElement = 0;
          }
        }
        
    ]]> </script>
    <g>
    <circle/>
    </g>

    <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="399" height="199" fill="none" stroke="black"/>
    
    <rect class="draggable" id="blue" x="30" y="30" width="80" height="80" fill="blue" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 46 18)" onmousedown="selectElement(evt)"/>
          
    <rect class="draggable" id="green" x="160" y="50" width="50" height="50" fill="green" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 51 11)" onmousedown="selectElement(evt)"/>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is only one way to make an element appear in front of another element in SVG and that is to remove the lower element then turn around and redraw it.  There is no z-index or other helpful attribute that you can set.  I spent a bit of time on this and that is my conclusion.

There is one upside and that is by removing and redrawing it, it ensures that the display order of all of the elements is maintained whereas if you have to maintain z-indexes, managing the numbers can cause its own set of issues.